# I am writing Launchd for my App to relaunch it when exits abnormally using KeepAlive SuccessfulExit in OSX

Tags: macos, launchd

I am writing Launchd for my App to relaunch it when exits abnormally  using KeepAlive  SuccessfulExit in OSX
Its not working for me when I am checking  it by  doing force quit to Application

See the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.name.myApp</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/al/bin/myApp.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it backwards. From [launchd.plist(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html):

```
       SuccessfulExit <boolean>
       If true, the job will be restarted as long as the program exits
       and with an exit status of zero.  If false, the job will be
       restarted in the inverse condition.
```

Set the key to `<false/>` and you should be good.